# Bold arrows in xymatrix

Tags: pdftex, arrows, xy-pic

How can I produce a bold arrow in the package `\xymatrix`? I've tried with `\ar@{\bf{->}}[r]` and similar alternatives without success.

Comment: If you use `dvips` you could use something like \ar@[|(3)]. More info in the pages 27 and 28 of the [XY-pic Reference Manual](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyrefer.pdf).

Comment: `\xymatrix{A \ar@*{[|(3)]}[r] & B}` with `pdflatex` warns that varying the arrow thickness is not implemented. :(

Comment: Thanks, I'm using ``pdflatex``, so I would very much appreciate a solution that works there. I'll add the tag.

Comment: @user17786 I'm afraid that you can't receive any better answer than "it's not implemented". Try contacting the maintainers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try compiling this document with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar@*{[|(3)]}[r] & B}
\end{document}
```

you receive the following warnings

```
<xymatrix 2x1

Xy-pic Warning: The linewidth 1.19994pt effect is not implemented
with the current driver. [notimpl:4].


Xy-pic Warning: The linewidth 1.19994pt effect is not implemented
with the current driver. [notimpl:4].


Xy-pic Warning: The linewidth 1.19994pt effect is not implemented
with the current driver. [notimpl:4].

44>
```

This means that the feature is not available with the current implementation of the `xypdf` driver (version 1.7)

Answer (score 3):

This might be considered "bad LaTeX", but I've made some arrows bold by just putting in a few on top of each other.

```
\xymatrix {
    & A \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\
      B \ar[rr] \ar[rr] \ar[rr] \ar[rr] & & C}
```

gives

[image]

Sorry if that isn't the most helpful, but at least works as a temporary solution/last resort.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy!  Repeat the arrow once with displacement `@<0.2mm>` and once with `@<-0.2mm>` or with whatever displacement you find pretty and with as many repetitions of various displacements as you like.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question directly but if you just want to **emphasize** some arrows you could use the style `\ar@{=>}` with `\xymatrix` and `\usepackage[all{xy}`.